# Does ModelMapper takes into consideration aspect advices

Tags: java, aspectj, aspect, modelmapper

We have implemented encryption and decryption as cross-cutting concern using aspectJ. We have used compile time weaving. Any field in our Entity object, we want to encrypt we annotate setter with @encrypt similarly, we annotate the getter with @decrypt. The around advice takes care of the encryption and decryption.

We are using modelmapper to create DTO  from the entity like below.
MyDTO myDTO = modelMapper.map(MyEntity, MyDTO.class);

My entity getter method is annotated with @decrypt . Would the decrypt advice be called in this case.
Similarly, in reverse case would the encrypt advice be called while calling setter.

Comment: Is this old question still relevant? I noticed it because it was edited by someone just now. If your are still looking for an answer, please let me know.

Comment: No, I am not looking for the answer now, please let me know, what needs to be done

Comment: Well, if you are no longer looking for an answer you do not need to do much. :-) You can e.g. delete the question, write an answer by yourself describing how you solved the problem (if you did) or just ignore it altogether.